# Angular 8 Resize element directive - set max and min resize width of element

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, resize

I created a directive for resizing element horizontally. It works totally fine, but I have a problem, once user push mouse on resizing too far on left or right, cursor position is not calculating properly. This causes that user for example resized sidebar to left too much, and to resize it to right once again, he needs to push mouse to right accordingly, how much it was pushed to the left.

I have added max-width and min-width properties in CSS, so element behaves exactly as expected, but not the logic. Here is my directive:

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, OnDestroy, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {fromEvent, Subject} from 'rxjs';
import {takeUntil} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Directive({
  selector: '[resizer]'
})
export class ResizeDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    width: number;
    oldX = 0;
    grabber = false;
    destroy$ = new Subject();

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.width= parseInt(this.el.nativeElement.parentNode.offsetWidth, 10);
    }

    @HostListener('document:mouseup', ['$event'])
    onMouseUp(): void {
        this.grabber = false;
        this.destroy$.next();
    }

    @HostListener('mousedown', ['$event']) onResize(event: MouseEvent, resizerCallback?: Function) {
        this.grabber = true;
        this.oldX = event.clientX;
        event.preventDefault();

        this.addMouseMoveListener();
    }

    resizer(offsetY: number): void {
        this.width += offsetX;
        this.el.nativeElement.parentNode.style.width= this.width+ 'px';
    }

    addMouseMoveListener(): void {
        fromEvent(document, 'mousemove')
            .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
            .subscribe(this.mouseMoveCallback.bind(this));
    }

    mouseMoveCallback(event: MouseEvent): void {
        if (!this.grabber) {
            return;
        }

        this.resizer(event.clientX- this.oldX);
        this.oldX = event.clientX;
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.destroy$.next();
    }

}
```

My question is, is it possible to set here a max element width and min element width to stop mousedown event? Like for example if element has `40vw` then stop resizing and calculating and accordingly, if element has `25vw` then stop mousedown event?

My second thought was to block cursor on resizing sidebar on mousedown, to avoid cursor moving away from resizing sidebar but I have no clue how to achieve that.

My third thought was to reset oldX variable to resize sidebar position.

Thanks in advance!